# Is there a way to count a number of distinct values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct-values

In PostgreSQL 9.4 I have a table:

```
id         p_id
PK        integer
-----------------
1           1
2           1
.............
123122       2233
```

Is there a way to count all distinct `p_id` values in the table with only one query (**without using subqueries**). I'm free to use any window-function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` modifier in the `count` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p_id) FROM mytable
```

Comment: Interesting, why does somenone downvote the post? Is it a bad way to do that?

Comment: Postgres and Hive are two databases where `count()` with a subquery using `distinct` is often faster than `count(distinct)`.  I sincerely doubt that the anonymous downvoter was thinking about this detail of the execution plan.  This is the correct answer.  And, the cases where `count(distinct)` produces a suboptimal execution plan are an opportunity for Postgres developers to further improve the database in the future.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I admit I did not know that about Postgres, thanks! Learnt something new today! I'll have to play around with my local database a bit to see how I can reproduce this.

Comment: @Mureinik . . . You can see the behavior on multi-processor servers.  The key idea is that the "aggregation" part of a `group by` runs in parallel, but the "function" part of evaluating an aggregation function is serialized.  This can have a big impact on performance.